# Layers disappearing from Layers panel

Tags: qgis, layers

Twice now when I have created new layers, most of the others disappeared from the layers panel.  The first time happened when I created a temporary scratch layer, the second time was when I created a grid via the Vector/Research Tools/create grid menu option (also a scratch layer).  I was concerned that the missing layers might be lost so I quit QGIS without saving the project.  When I reopened the project all the missing layers were there, minus the unsaved scratch/grid layers.[image: This is the project before the addition of the grid scratch layer][image: This is the project after the addition of the grid scratch layer, showing a much reduced number of layers in the layers panel]

I am running QGIS-3.28.8 Firenze on an M1 MacBook Pro running OS Ventura (13.4.1).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the others disappearing from the layers panel - could you share a screenshot of before and after? And are the layers still visible on the canvas?

Comment: Yes of course.  Most of the other layers disappeared from the panel, though their content remained on the screen.  Before and after screengrabs ato follow.